# bash script to checkout git repo on newly created instance

Tags: git, bash

I am kind of new to bash so please bear with me. I am writing a script which is suppose install git in newly created linux instance on cloud and then checkout a repo that is a private repo on github which requires credentials. I can checkout by providing credentials but I do not want to add my credentials in the script so wondering if there is any other options or suggestions please.

thanks all.

Best Regards
SI

Answer (score 2):

Yup, this is exactly what [git read-only deploy keys](https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys) are for.

> A deploy key is an SSH key that is stored on your server and grants access to a single GitHub repository. They are often used to clone repositories during deploys or continuous integration runs.

See also https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of achieving this (assuming you are using SSH urls, if not, then you should be using them):

1. Using deploy keys as @Jeff mentioned. Here you add deploy keys generated in the server, in your project settings via Github.
2. You can also use ssh key forwarding in which your ssh key is used. Look into this: https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/